# I need to create and sort new array with php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to create a new array from an existing one, choose from an array of all the old data that coincide in one field and bring it into the new array, given that the name was one and the necessary data are collected together.

```
class Data{
public $name;
public $city;
public $country;
public $partnername;

public function __construct($name, $city, $country, $partnername)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->city = $city;
    $this->country = $country;
    $this->partnername = $partnername;
}}
```

Array to sort

```
$array = array(
new Data("Serghio", "Madrid", "Spain", "C#"),
new Data("John", "London", "England", "PHP"),
new Data("Ivan", "Moscow", "Russia", "C++"),
new Data("John", "London", "England", "C++"),
new Data("Smith", "Milan", "Italy", "PHP"),
new Data("John", "London", "England", "Java"));
```

Loop

```
$isVisited = array(count($array));
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
  $isVisited[$i] = true;
  for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++){
    if($i != $j && @!$isVisited[$j]) {
        $isVisited[$j] = true;
        if($array[$i]->name == $array[$j]->name) {
            print_r($array[$j]);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}}
```

New array

```
$newarray = array(
"Serghio", "Madrid", "Spain", "C#",
"John", "London", "England", "PHP", "C++", "Java",
"Ivan", "Moscow", "Russia", "C++",   
"Smith", "Milan", "Italy", "PHP",);
```

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you explained what your problem was or made clear what was your *desired* outcome as opposed to what is your output currently...

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Comment: Yes this answer slove my problem, thanks Peter. You helped me a lot.

Comment: If it solved your problem then please go ahead and mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: but as I can now get access to the names of hotels I need to pull them in an array?

Comment: You have $newarray as an associative array. Is that not acceptable? Just loop through with `for each ($newarray as $k=>$v)... ` and you have the name in $k & the rest in the array $v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a single loop through and be a lot more efficient. Use an associative array instead of a normal index to make it easy to identify.

```
# $isVisited = array(count($array)); // This does not do what you think it does
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if (!isset($newarray[$array[$i]->name]))
        $newarray[$array[$i]->name] = array($array[$i]->city, $array[$i]->country, $array[$i]->partnername);
    else
        array_push($newarray[$array[$i]->name], $array[$i]->partnername);
}
```